# how to create Mib file in java.I googled for it but cant find anything helpful. I am using snm4j and snmp4j-agent libarraies

Tags: java, snmp, mib, oid, snmpv3

I googled for it but can't find anything helpful. I am using `snm4j` and `snmp4j-agent` libararies.

//here is my sample oid

```
final OID oid1 = new OID(".1.3.6.1.2.1.6666.2.2.2.1");
```

//while quering through net-snmp client i got the following result:

```
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.1.1 = INTEGER: 2
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.1.2 = INTEGER: 5
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.1.3 = INTEGER: 1
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.1.4 = INTEGER: 6
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.1.5 = INTEGER: 7
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.1.6 = INTEGER: 3
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.1.7 = INTEGER: 4
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.2.1 = INTEGER: 2
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.2.2 = INTEGER: 1
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.2.3 = INTEGER: 5
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.2.4 = INTEGER: 5
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.2.5 = INTEGER: 4
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.2.6 = INTEGER: 3
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.2.7 = INTEGER: 1
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.3.1 = INTEGER: 7
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.3.2 = INTEGER: 24
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.3.3 = INTEGER: 17
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.3.4 = INTEGER: 18
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.3.5 = INTEGER: 23
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.3.6 = INTEGER: 7
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.3.7 = INTEGER: 7
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.4.1 = INTEGER: 2
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.4.2 = INTEGER: 2
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.4.3 = INTEGER: 2
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.4.4 = INTEGER: 2
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.4.5 = INTEGER: 2
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.4.6 = INTEGER: 2
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.4.7 = INTEGER: 2
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.5.1 = STRING: "Line Card"
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.5.2 = STRING: "E1/E2/E3 Int Card"
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.5.3 = STRING: "STM1 Interface Card"
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.5.4 = STRING: "STM1 Interface Card"
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.5.5 = STRING: "HS-CPU"
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.5.6 = STRING: "Control Card"
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.5.7 = STRING: "E1/E2/E3 Int Card"
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.6.1 = STRING: "10:22:02:04:05:99"
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.6.2 = STRING: "10:23:02:24:05:91"
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.6.3 = STRING: "10:22:92:04:05:99"
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.6.4 = STRING: "10:23:12:94:05:08"
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.6.5 = STRING: "10:23:02:94:05:01"
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.6.6 = STRING: "10:22:02:14:05:99"
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.6666.2.2.2.1.6.7 = STRING: "10:22:02:24:05:99"
```